# PHP MS SQL - Multiple value one field pass in a stored procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am having a bit of trouble with MS SQL and PHP. Would you guide me with this?

Here is my story:

I have a delivery report. The report have filters. Take a look at my form:

[Delivery Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vsd7d.png)

Now the filters are working fine. I can retrieve data. But my boss wants my filter to be multiple value per field.

Example:

In the Sales Group field, If I put "01, 07" all the delivery from sales group 01 and 07 would appear in the table. Currently I am using LIKE condition.

Now my question is, how can I pass comma delimited values into my MS SQL stored procedure?

Maybe my approach is wrong. Is there other way to do this? Is it on MS Sql part or the PHP part?

Here's my sql query: (UPdate: Here is the final QUERY that solved my problem. **Thanks PSA**)

```html
-- inventoryDetailed '0', '10', '1', '', '', '', '02/01/2018', '02/28/2018'
-- inventoryDetailed '0', '10', '1', NULL, NULL, NULL, '01/01/2018', '05/31/2018'
-- exec inventoryDetailed 0, 10, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, '01/01/2018', '07/28/2018'
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[inventoryDetailed]
@start int,
@pageSize int,
@userId bigint,
@salesGroupCode nvarchar(10),
@salesOfficeCode nvarchar(10),
@salesDistrictCode nvarchar(10),
@DtRcvFrom DATETIME,
@DtRcvTo   DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @storeSalesGroup nvarchar(max)

DECLARE @salesGroupTable TABLE
(
   salesGroup nvarchar(10)
)

SET @storeSalesGroup = @salesGroupCode
while len(@salesGroupCode) > 0
begin
  --exec YourSP left(@S, charindex(',', @S+',')-1)

  insert into @salesGroupTable values(left(@salesGroupCode, charindex(',', @salesGroupCode +',')-1))
  set @salesGroupCode = stuff(@salesGroupCode, 1, charindex(',', @salesGroupCode+','), '')
end


SELECT d.SGrp as salesGroupCode,
    d.SGrpNm as salesGroup,
    d.SOffc as salesOfficeCode,
    d.SOffcNm as salesOffice,
    d.SDst as salesDistrictCode,
    d.SDstNm as salesDistrict,
    a.CustCode as customerCode,
    d.CustNm as customer,
    c.MatrlCode as materialCode,
    c.MatDesc as material,
    b.Qty as qty,
    b.ExpDt as batch,
    datepart(wk, a.DtRcv) as week,
    a.DtRcv as dateRcvd,
    e.LName + ', ' + e.FName as diser,
    overall_count = COUNT(*) OVER()
FROM   [BigEMerchandiser].[dbo].[tbl_Inventory_H] as a
  
    INNER JOIN [BigEMerchandiser].[dbo].[tbl_Inventory_D] as b
    ON a.TransCtr = b.TransCtr

    INNER JOIN BigEMasterData.dbo.tbl_Materials as c
    ON b.Material = c.ExtMatGrp
   
    INNER JOIN BigEMasterData.dbo.tbl_Customers as d
    ON a.CustCode = d.CustCode
    
    inner JOIN [BigESentData].[dbo].[tbl_sentRegistration] as e
    on a.CreatedBy = e.CellNum

    inner join BigEUsers.dbo.user_role_area as f
    on d.SDst = f.area_id

    inner join BigEUsers.dbo.users as g
    on f.role_id = g.role_id

WHERE  datepart(wk, a.DtRcv) BETWEEN datepart(wk, @DtRcvFrom) AND datepart(wk, @DtRcvTo)
AND (d.SGrp IN (SELECT salesGroup from @salesGroupTable))
OR (ISNULL(@storeSalesGroup,'')='')
AND    d.SOffc LIKE ISNULL('%' + @salesOfficeCode + '%', d.SOffc)
AND    d.SDst LIKE ISNULL('%' + @salesDistrictCode + '%', d.SDst)
AND    g.id = @userId

ORDER BY a.DtRcv desc

OFFSET @start ROWS
FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY;

END
```

Any tips and suggestion would be much appreciated. Thankyou so much.

**EDIT:**

**Thanks PSK for the idea.**

What I did is pass the string from PHP. Example: '01, 07'.

Then, in MS SQL, I created a table variable.

```
DECLARE @salesGroupTable TABLE
(
  salesGroup nvarchar(10)
)
```

Next, I will get split the string passed from PHP ('01, 07') and then insert it to the table variable.

Next, I will use that table variable in my IN condition.

```
WHERE  d.SGrp IN (SELECT salesGroup from @salesGroupTable)
```

Now, it is working fine. It is working as expected.

But if the user didn't input anything, I must return all the results. Hope you can help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Table-valued parameters are not yet supported by the `PHP MSSQL Driver`. So you have to live with passing a comma separated string to the stored procedure from your PHP code.

More details on data type supported by [PHP MSSQL Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296193(SQL.90).aspx)

Use inbuilt function STRING_SPLIT to get the desired behavior.

You can implement your code like following.

```
DECLARE @Codes NVARCHAR(400) = 'Code1,Code2,Code3,Code4,Code5'  

SELECT * FROM [Your_Table] UT
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT IN_Code  
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Codes, ',')  

) INPUT_DATA
ON INPUT_DATA.IN_Code = UT.Code
```

Comment: Hi PSK. Thanks for your comment. It created an idea in me. Here's what I have tried. I passed the string from PHP. example: '01,07'. Then in MS SQL, I wills split the string and insert it to a table variable(@salesGroupTable).  so the '01, 07' string will become two rows, 01, and 07. now my where clause there is a IN condition (), (SELECT salesGroup FROM @salesGroupTable). It is working fine. But I want to retrieve all the data if the didn't supply any string. Kindly see my edited question. Thank you so much..

Comment: Put 1 mor additional OR @input = ‘’

Comment: Where salesgroup in ( select salesgroup from @salesgrouptable) OR @input=‘’

Comment: Hi @PSK, thanks. I did what you suggested. It is fine. It is working. Byt if I supplied a text, it still show all the results. Would you look at my new query? I will replace my query on my question. Thankyou...

Comment: please see my question. I have now changed the query and applied your sugggestion. Thankyou...

Comment: can you change ISNULL(@salesGroupCode,’’)=‘’

Comment: HI PSK, still the same. If blank, shows all the records. It is fine. But if I add '01,07' still it shows all the records.

Comment: You are manipulating @salesGroupCode in the while loop, it might be setting it empty causing this issue, copy it to a local variable and compare with the copied variable. It will fix the issue

Comment: Hi PSK! Wow  you saved my job! :) Thank you so much for guiding me till the problem is solved. I have already update my query and posted you suggestion. I have added @storeSalesGroup to store my string. Couldn't thank you more.

Comment: I am glad it helped you. You can always up vote the answer :)

Comment: I can't upvote :( because my reputation is low. but I have selected it as the correct answer.